# Content / footer at bottom of page in Chrome, but keeps scrolling upward in Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress, footer, parallax

I posted this question in WordPress Stack, but now they're telling me I should post in in Stack Exchange because this is probably a purely css problem.

I am developing a WordPress page with a fixed background, so the content area scrolls up and down. I guess it's parallax, or something like it. When I view the page in Chrome, the end of the content area meets the footer correctly, and the footer is the last thing you see at the bottom of the page. So far, so good.

But in Firefox, the content area scrolls upward another few hundred pixels, so that you can see the bottom of the fixed background picture below the bottom edge of the footer.

In order to understand the problem, view the following link in both Chrome and Firefox to see the differences. What I want it to do in Firefox is what it is doing in Chrome:

[About page](http://5bf.0e2.myftpupload.com/about/?nocache=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a hardcoded height in your code.

```
#second-string {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fee;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3000px; // Overwrite this or remove it, if you can
    margin-top: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 8px -10px #000, inset 0px -11px 8px -10px #000;
}
```

Comment: I would love to not have to hard code that height. But if I remove the height, or if I use height:auto, or if I use height:100% what happens is that pink background area is too short, and my content sections are set against the background image. I suppose I could try putting a background color on my content "sections" (divs with content within the main content div). Thanks.

Comment: Well, I stand corrected. Your answer works. I removed the height property from that div, and now it works exactly like I want it to work. Very cool.

Comment: Glad I could help you out! Keep on coding! :)